# Dropping rows from pandas dataframe based on floatpoint range

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Goal: remove all rows from series where value is within range -0.2 to 0.2. Datatype for values is float. Is there any way to do this that doesn't require converting the type?

Sample data:

| index |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-31 00:44:09 | 0.1515 |
| 2020-12-31 00:40:57 | 0.4404 |
| 2020-12-31 00:40:19 | 0.0000 |
| 2020-12-31 00:37:54 | -0.2263 |
| 2020-12-31 00:23:38 | -0.1234 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `~` for invert mask in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if `s` is `Series`:

```
s = s[~s.between(-0.2, 0.2)]
```

If working with column `col` use:

```
df = df[~df['col'].between(-0.2, 0.2)]
```